# Best way to run python script globally in Linux?

Tags: python, linux

so the answer to this question seems to be in the /usr/local/bin folder, which is fine for a single script file but my program has multiple .py files and folders containing HTML files which the program relies on like so:

```
program
    -templates
        file1.html
        file2.html
    script.py
    class.py
    another_class.py
```

How would I go about setting this up globally under linux?

Comment: Provide a `setup.py` that installs your package and any scripts that it provides.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how is this a duplicate of that answer? I'm not asking how to make setup.py file

Comment: But you want to know how to install your script globally and access the functionality in your package, which *can be achieved using a `setup.py`*. If that question doesn't answer yours, please edit to clarify what you still need to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your program to */usr/loca/myprog* and then create a symlink from */usr/local/myprog/scrip.py* to */usr/loca/bin*. This assumes it is *script.py* you want to be available as an executable globally.
Alternatively, create a shell script /usr/local/bin/myprog.sh that invokes your python script.

```
#!/bin/sh
python /usr/local/myprog/script.py
```

Of course this is not really a clean solution. The suggestion in the comments to create a distutils package based on setup.py file is much better.